# How to show this is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to prove that $\mathcal{Z}=\{A \subset \Omega : \exists B \in  \mathcal{V},  A = f^{-1}  (B)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ generated by the function $f$, that maps $\Omega$ to another space $S$ endowed with a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{V}$.

Usually, I would check $\mathcal{Z}$ for $\sigma$-algebra properties. But inverse relation makes things complicated.

I'm not really sure how to start. Any Hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know if $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Something's screwy with your definition: $\mathcal{Z}$ is the thing you're defining, but it occurs in the set comprehension too. Probably you need a different letter on the left of the "=". In any case, you want: the collection of all $f$-preimages of sets in some $\sigma$-algebra on the range of $f$, yes? $f$ maps $\Omega$ to ... $S$? why the font change?

Comment: @ Brian. Thank you for your solution. I'm sorry, I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

First let's straighten out the notation.
Suppose $f \colon A \to B$ is a function, and $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $B$. Let $\mathcal{R} = \{f^{-1}(Y) \mid Y \in \mathcal{S}\}$. You want to show that $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $A$.

- **$A \in \mathcal{R}$**

  because $A=f^{-1}(B)$ and $B \in \mathcal{S}$.
- **If $X \in \mathcal{R}$ then $A\!\setminus\! X \in \mathcal{R}$**

  If $X \in \mathcal{R}$ then $X = f^{-1}(Y)$ for some $Y \in \mathcal{S}$. Then $B\!\setminus\! Y \in \mathcal{S}$, so $f^{-1}(B\!\setminus\! Y) = A \!\setminus\! f^{-1}(Y) = A \!\setminus\! X \in \mathcal{R}$.

Finally,

- **$\mathcal{R}$ is closed under countable unions**

  If $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a countable family of members of $\mathcal{R}$, then each $X_n = f^{-1}(Y_n)$ for some $Y_n \in \mathcal{S}$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ contains the union of the $(Y_n)$, so $\mathcal{R}$ contains the $f$-preimage of their union. But $f^{-1}$ "distributes" over unions, so $f^{-1}(\bigcup_n Y_n) = \bigcup_n f^{-1}(Y_n) = \bigcup_n X_n \in \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: hi Brian, thank you for that approach. May I kindly ask you to adjust your solution to the new notation $V$...thx!